# When number reaches every nth value inside nested loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Purpose: A user can choose a Product Type and variation of that Product Type. I need to track every Product Type added and how many variations were added. For Example, 
item 1: Shirt > Long Sleeve (1) 
item 2: Shirt > V neck (3) 
item 3: Pants > Jeans (1)

The total amount pertains to the variation of the product. I'd like to have something happen whenever a user selects 4th variation of the same type. For this example, I want something to happen to the Product type Shirt, as currently long sleeve + v neck = 4

I have two nested loops. First one is looping through each product type, and inner loop should loop through each variation and get the sum.

This is a good starting point but I can't seem to get passed the for loop to check for every nth value of the total # of variations.

```
jQuery('.product').each(function(i, objP){
    var sum = 0,
    min = 4,
    max = 5;        
    jQuery(objP).find('.product-variation-quantity').each(function(ii, objC){
        sum += parseInt(jQuery(objC).text());
        return sum;
        for ( var x = 0; x < min * max; x += min) {
            if ( sum == x ) {
                var sum_id = jQuery(objP).attr('id');
                console.log(sum_id);
                //product quantity has reached min to pass
            }
            else {
                //has not reached min
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any help?
note: objP and objC are used to track the contextual `this` 
note2: to clarify: on every 4th, 8th, 12th etc value, something will happen, not every 4th, 5th, 6th

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the issue you're having.  But among the things I'm thinking is that `sum == x` should be `if (sum >= x)` if you're just trying to reach a minimum.

Comment: you are returning sum before you start the inner loop..

Comment: The statements following `return sum;` never get executed.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I need to track every fourth value. So if the user keeps adding, lets say long-sleeves, and gets it up to 5. The total would be 8. So there would be 2 instances where the if statement will be true.

Comment: what is the role of the max value?

Comment: role of max is to limit an event (which I haven't shown for the sake of simplicity) that occurs on success, (reaching 4th value). It's in a way, a cap

Comment: Can `max` be ignored in answering this question? I don't get what "limiting an event" would practically mean. If it is important, please elaborate.

Comment: yes, max can be ignored. what's most important is "every nth value of the total"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a bug in your code, it's where you `return sum;` in the nested loop. The `for` loop after this will never execute.

I suggest this code:

```
jQuery('.product').each(function(i, objP){
    var sum = 0,
    min = 4,
    max = 5;   
    var ind = 1; 
    jQuery(objP).find('.product-variation-quantity').each(function(ii, objC){
        sum = parseInt(jQuery(objC).text());
        if (sum > 0 && sum % 4 == 0) {
            // Do something
        }

    });
});
```

[Here's codepen sample.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbzLVg)

Comment: oh, note that you don't actually need all those `min`, `max`, `ind` vars

Comment: Max is related but I guess not for this one specific question. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

What about this: in case 8 items of the same variation are selected, the console will read

```
[id] has crossed 2x4 items
```

Code:

```
jQuery('.product').each(function(i, objP){
    var min = 4,
        max = 5,
        sum_id;        
    jQuery(objP).find('.product-variation-quantity').each(function(ii, objC){
        var count = parseInt(jQuery(objC).text());
        if ( count < min ) {
            //product quantity has not reached min
        }
        else {
            // product quantity has reached min to pass
            sum_id = jQuery(objP).attr('id');
            console.log(sum_id + ' has crossed ' + min + 'x' 
                    + Math.floor(count/min) + ' items');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this fires every time after min has occured. it should be limited to every 4th value. Think of it as a promo, if user gets every 4 shirts, they get one free, not every 2 shirts and 2 pants.

Comment: Then why do you even keep a sum, if you just read the number of shirts already? I will adapt my answer not to use sums any more....

Comment: it's not total sum, it's sum of product type

Comment: But when you get `parseInt(jQuery(objC).text())`, what are you reading? The number of items of that variant? Is the minimum on that value? Can you check the code now?

Comment: Getting the value of each variation. 
The piece that's most helpful in your code is Math.floor(count/min). But else{} is still being fired everytime, the purpose is not to know how many times every nth value has fired, but rather do something